# Insert/Update/Index many rows (10 billion) numbers as values

Tags: sql, database, data-structures, bigdata, nosql

I need to insert 10 billion rows and update their values few times.

Table structure:

```
Column1 Column2 Count
1       1       99
1       2       10003
1       3       1
1       4       23
1       5       9994
...
99999   1       2
99999   2       2233
99999   3       5904
99999   4       12
99999   5       4598435
...
```

I need `Column1` to be indexed.
In one table `Count` will be Integer in another it will be Double.

What database suits best for my needs?
I was told I should use NoSQL but there are so many of them.

Comment: According to my opinion the best suited databases for you would be `ORACLE` or `SYABSE` OR upto some extent you can use `SQL-SERVER`.

Comment: Oracle, SQL Server are proprietary databases that require license purchasing. For a start, I suppose Postgres is most acceptable option, isnt it?

Comment: @xacinay Same architecture but with less rows (400 million) works well with MySQL for me. Do you think Postgres is better for this task and why?

Comment: Postgres is a very scalable db (including multicore). Watch [this comparison](http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/MySQL_vs_PostgreSQL). Also, it has a very well-optimized compiled functions and variety of indexes for all ocasions. Postgres's QueryOptimier is another reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in any mainstream RDBMS that would make this hard or even impossible. All your requirements are **trivial** for any RDBMS.

What you need is a single table with a single index on it. This does not stress any system architecturally.

Be aware that RAM is likely to be not enough to cache all data. This means that every access will hit the disk. You need disks that have enough IOPS.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a database you know well as long as it can handle your required throughput. So I assume since you are asking your preferred database hasn't met your requirements.

If you require high throughput with consistent sub-millisecond lookup latency take a look at [Aerospike](http://www.arerospike.com) which is used a lot in the ADTech industry. See this [Case Study from AppNexus and Intel](http://aerospike.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Aerospike-AppNexus-SSD-Case-Study_Final.pdf). Aerospike is an open source, distributed, in memory and/or SSD NOSQL KV database with support for UDFs and Secondary Indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start with PostgreSQL. It has no row count limitations [manifested here](http://www.postgresql.org/about/). If you face any perfromance troubles with it, you may think again about some NoSQL solution. But it's more probable, Postgres will fit your requirements. It's very mature today.